# Prevent SSRS from opening multple authentication windows

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, ssrs-2017

Setup SSRS 2017
32bit ODBC driver for Snowflake
I am able to connect and retrieve my data but, the drive must be set to Authenticator: externalbrowser. This is annoying because it pops up a window for each dataset when it runs. There could easily be a report with 10+ datasets resulting in 10 browser windows, is there anyway to silence the authentication? or reduce it to 1 per report

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Using Connection Caching to Minimize the Number of Prompts for Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#label-browser-based-sso-connection-caching). We had the same issue when connecting to Snowflake using Excel. This account level parameter change resolved our issue.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this sounds like exactly what we are looking for.  Let me test it and come back with vaildation.